# Is there a simple explanation of what a compiler is?

Tags: compiler-construction, terminology

In trying to provide a simple answer to a post about a "[C++ compiled app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155385/c-compiled-application/4155522#4155522)" I was surprised that there weren't any questions or answers about this basic topic. Even searches on Meta didn't find anything helpful, whether on [explaining compilers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=compiler+explanation) or [beginning compiler questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginning+compiler+questions) in general.

We want Stackoverflow to be a good place to find answers about programming. We shouldn't leave something so fundamental to Wikipedia.  A simple analogy would be asking a master carpenter what a 10-penny nail is and getting brushed off. Sure it's a simple question but a carpenter who thinks explaining something so simple is beneath him/her is just being a snob in the best case, politely, or a jerk if otherwise.

At the very least, this question provides a place to gather links to compiler-related explanations inside or outside of Stackoverflow.

[Id make this CW but don't see the checkbox, has it been moved or deleted?]

In that spirit, I provide the link to the Wikipedia on compilers.  Please edit this post with more links to compiler explanations.

Wikipedia entry on [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

Comment: Cool question! Plumbing, electrical work, or house construction might be a good area for a metaphor.

Comment: "We shouldn't leave something so fundamental to Wikipedia." - I object. If there's already a flawless general explanation on Wikipedia (or anywhere else where it can be found via Google easily), there's no need to replicate this information here.

Comment: I think the wikipedia entry is pretty darn informative.  It's hard to me improve on that one, unless you set a criteria such as, explain in 20 words what a compiler is (to make is a 'simple' explaination).

Comment: Somehow, it does seem to me that the Wikipedia page answers the question perfectly. But I guess we can give it a shot.

Comment: Wikipedia's a pretty good place for programming information; I go there regularly for overviews on unfamiliar concepts.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that we replicate the information.  By providing a link to Wikipedia we both endorse the information on Wikipedia and provide a local nexus for links of a similar nature.

Comment: Perhaps there is a need for stack exchange site for "self-styled basement programmers"? I realize that this sounds more arrogant than I want it to sound.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with questions who's best/ideal answer is a link to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Short Answer

To just summarize very briefly what the role of a compiler would be and leave the extensive explanation to [Wikipedia's Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) page, I'd just say that in general a compiler is a computer software which transforms an input source code written in a given form (usually targeted towards humans for readability) into an output program in a compressed form (usually targeted towards machines for execution). Alternatively, said software might go through several stages and produce multiple intermediate forms during processing, and might need to execute multiple passes and merge multiples input sources into one or more output.

The compiler thus simply acts as a static translator for a (usually formal) human language into a (usually even more formal and minimalistic) machine language or instruction set.

### Some Distinctions to Keep in Mind

This being said, usually the term "compilation" gets mangled with other terms describing other steps of a full software production cycle, and might be used to refer to steps like [pre-processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) (to prepare the input before processing and apply other kinds of transformations in advance, for instance possibly using [meta-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) concepts) or [linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(software)) (to assemble multiple intermediate objects).

A typical example could be the one of a C program, being compiled with a single command-line but which actually processes multiple `.c` (source) and `.h` (header) files into multiple `.o` (object) file and might then link these to multiple `.a` (assembly/library) files to produce an output program (`.exe`, `.out`, ...) or another `.a` or `.dll` or `.so` (assembly for dynamic or shared library for different platforms).

Said steps could also be performed by executing multiple command-lines instead, to dissociate the different operations occurring.

[image: Multi-Language Compilation Process]

---

This obviously is a very high-level explanation geared towards the IT-world, but there's no doubt that you can refer to the term "compiler" for other software and machines transforming an input of any kind into somehow executable or usable output of another kind.

---

*Graphics courtesy of [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)'s [Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) page*

Comment: Hey, 2 up-votes. Actually surprised, as the more I tried to "improve" that stub answer, the more I felt that I would either need to detail it more to the point of reaching an essay-like answer, or need to strip it down again to go back to a one or 2 sentences answers. Interesting question to try to answer in way that is generic, synthetic but not misleading...

Comment: You have encountered the exact reason why I asked the question all those years ago.

Answer (score 5):

I was about to provide an answer, but the first sentence on the Wikipedia article is virtually the same as what I was going to type:

> A compiler is a computer program *[...]* that transforms source code written in a programming language *[...]* into another computer language *[...]*

Comment: Huzzah for Wikipedia quoting the Dragon Book. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I know there might be even better explanations on this, but since I had a hard time finding an answer myself years ago, I decided to write an article about it, today that I finally have an answer. I hope it helps somebody not to go down the rabbit hole again that I had to go. I tried to be very detailed, yet explain in the simplest way possible.

https://kyxey.medium.com/what-is-a-compiler-how-does-it-work-an-easy-explanation-482a7280f1be

Please let me know if you had any more questions regarding this, and I’ll be very happy to help you through understanding it.

Comment: I like your approach. Have you considered creating a part 2 and discuss liveness analysis and register allocation?